# Log4j2 in OpenOffice Extension

Tags: netbeans, log4j, slf4j, log4j2, openoffice.org

I've created an extension for OpenOffice (Writer if that matters) in Java. I have used SLF4J and Log4J2 for my logging. Everything works perfectly in my unit tests; however, when my plugin runs in OpenOffice I get the following error message on the console (Linux terminal):

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

I'm building the extension with NetBeans using the OpenOffice plugin. I changed the build script so that my log4j2.xml file is included at the root of BOTH the `oxt` and `jar` files... yet clearly it cannot be found.

**2 Questions**:

1. Where do I put my log4j2.xml file so that OpenOffice can "see" it?
2. Short of that, how can I go about manually configuring Log4J2 so that I don't need to worry about the location of the config file? I only want a simple `FileAppender` with a `PatternLayout`

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue of not being able to find the log4j2.xml file (isn't it always?)

Here is what I put at the **VERY** top of the first class that is loaded:

```
/* THIS MUST BE FIRST!!! */
static {
    final String configFile = MyClass.class.getResource("/log4j2.xml").getFile();        
    final LoggerContext ctx = Configurator.initialize("", MyClass.class.getClassLoader(), "jar:" + configFile);        
    ctx.start();    
}
```

Then I just configured SLF4J and Log4j normally:

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```